# Probability of A and B occurring at the same time?

Tags: probability

I am a little confused by this notion. So the probability of both A occurring and B occurring, is only equal to P(A)P(B) when the two events are independent. But it seems to me that a lot of the times the way we figure out P(A intersection B) is by doing just that: P(A)P(B). Is there a case when the two probabilities are not to be multiplied?

Comment: Well, when they're not independent - they're dependent. If $n$ is integer between 1 and 10, $A$ is probability of $n$ being even, $B$ is probability of $n$ being odd, then they're dependent, so $P(A \cap B) = 0 \neq \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: And for dependent we mean the outcome of $A$ doesn't affect the outcome of $B$. So if you're familiar with conditional probability, $P(A | B) = P(A)$. (It should be defined the other way I believe.)

Comment: For another trivial example, consider a fair coin.  There are two sides to the coin, one of which shows "heads" and is painted red, the other shows "tails" and is painted blue.  The coin is flipped once.  The probability that the coin landed on the red side is $\frac{1}{2}$.  The probability the coin landed on heads is also $\frac{1}{2}$.  The probability that the coin landed on a red side and on heads in that one same flip is *also* $\frac{1}{2}$ (*remember, the red side IS the head side*).  Here, we don't multiply the probability of it being red with the probability of it being heads.

Comment: An astute observer will recognize this trivial example leading to a more general trivial example... suppose $0<Pr(A)<1$ and let $A=B$.  Then $Pr(A)Pr(B)<Pr(A\cap B) = Pr(A\cap A)=Pr(A)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are $5$ red balls and $5$ blue balls in an urn.  Two balls are drawn.  What is the probability that both are red?

It depends on whether or not the first ball is replaced in the urn before the second one is drawn.  If it replaced, then the first draw has no effect on the second.  The events are independent and the probability is $$\frac12\cdot\frac12=\frac14$$

If the first ball is not replaced, then the events are not independent, because the first draw changes the number of red and blue balls in the urn.
The probability that the first ball is red is still $\frac12$, of course.  What is the probability that the second ball is red?  If the first ball drawn is red, then there are $4$ red balls out of $9$ left in the urn, so we have a probability of $\frac49$ that the second ball is red, if the first one is red.  Similarly, if the first ball is black, we have a probability of $\frac59$ that the second ball is red.  Of course, each color has probability $\frac12$ on the first draw, so the probability that the second ball is red is $$\frac12\cdot\frac49+ \frac12\cdot\frac59=\frac12$$

However, the probability that both balls are red is not $\frac12\cdot\frac12$.  Indeed, we saw above that the probability is $$\frac12\cdot\frac49=\frac29$$